# kendo grid in inline editing mode with Dropdownlist required field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid in inline editing mode. When I press "Add new item" button, new row is added. some editable fields are ForeignKey column in the grid, if i fill the text fields in the new records without filling or select the dropdownlist fields for ForeignKey columns, a null values are set for ForeignKey  fields.

the question , how to enforce the user to select dropdownlist and make this field is required on "update" button click action.

i am using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dropdownlists are binded to non nullable values, and are you using the EditorTemplate provided for the foreign key columns?

Comment: the field binded to dropdownlist in the view model is nullable. that because i have legacy application.